# regular expression and escaping

Tags: java, regex

Sorry if this has been asked, my search brought up many off topic posts.

I'm trying to convert wildcards from a user defined search string (wildcard is "*") to PostgreSQL like wildcard "%".

I'd like to handle escaping so that `"%" => "\%"` and `"\*" => "*"`

I know I could replace `\*` with something else prior to replacing `*` and then swap it back, but I'd prefer not to and instead only convert `*` using a pattern that selects it when not proceeded by `\`.

```
String convertWildcard(String like)
{
    like = like.replaceAll("%", "\\%");
    like = like.replaceAll("\\*", "%");
    return like;
}

Assert.assertEquals("%", convertWildcard("*"));
Assert.assertEquals("\\%", convertWildcard("%"));
Assert.assertEquals("*", convertWildcard("\\*")); // FAIL

Assert.assertEquals("a%b", convertWildcard("a*b"));
Assert.assertEquals("a\\%b", convertWildcard("a%b"));
Assert.assertEquals("a*b", convertWildcard("a\\*b")); // FAIL
```

Ideas welcome.

**EDIT**

To clarify,

I want a method that makes 1 or more `String.replaceAll` calls to convert a string so that

- occurrences of `%` become `\%`,
- occurrences of `*` become `%` and
- occurrences of `\*` become `*`.

The best answer will use the least calls to `String.replaceAll`.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Could you clarify what you're trying to do and what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need what is called "Negative Lookbehind". To select all `%` not preceded by `\`:

`(?<!\\)%` (pure regex expression)

to use it in Java you need to add some masking:

`string.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)%", "*");`

Comment: thanks serg, to fit the question, your answer is `like = like.replaceAll("%", "\\%"); like = like.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\*", "%"); like = like.replaceAll("\\*", "*"); return like;`. looks like a good answer to me. p.

Comment: actually that last replaceall should be `like = like.replaceAll("\\\\\\*", "*");`

Answer (score 1):

Note also that you aren't escaping your backslashes enough in some of your assert tests. See the section marked "Regular Expressions, Literal Strings and Backslashes" in http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Comment: ah, you're right .. i should have run that before posting eh ;)